# Angular ActivateRoute will activate change detection

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I notice that angular ActivatedRoute will activate change detection immediately, which will cause `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error. How could I avoid it?

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscriptions.push(this.pageService.pageChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.currentPage = this.pageService.currentPageData();
    }));
    this.route.params
      .switchMap(params => {
        console.log("route.params.switchMap called: ", params);
        const requestedPageNumber = parseInt(params['page'], 10);
        return this.wizard.getPage(requestedPageNumber);
      })
      .subscribe((refocus) => {
        console.log("route.params subscribed called: ", refocus);
        this.refocus = !!refocus;
      });
    this.subscriptions.push(this.pageService.saveChanges.subscribe(() => {
      if (this.page) {
        this.page.saveData();
      }
    }));
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCoF4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Although It isn't a clean solution, I recommend a `setTimeout()`. This do an asyncronous-like execution on lifecycle hook.

Example:

```
setTimeout(() => {
 this.route.params
  .switchMap(params => {
    console.log("route.params.switchMap called: ", params);
    const requestedPageNumber = parseInt(params['page'], 10);
    return this.wizard.getPage(requestedPageNumber);
  })
  .subscribe((refocus) => {
    console.log("route.params subscribed called: ", refocus);
    this.refocus = !!refocus;
  });
  this.subscriptions.push(this.pageService.saveChanges.subscribe(() => {
    if (this.page) {
      this.page.saveData();
    }
  }));
), 1000};
```

Comment: Better to use ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() (if you need to) as that is its purpose